# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire

Just bumped my angularfire2 and firebase and now getting:

`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'`

Tried importing `import "rxjs/add/operator/map";`

But does not work.

What is further confusing, is that map exists: https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_list_observable_.firebaselistobservable.html

Version:
`"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",
"firebase": "^3.6.8"`

(this is also an ionic 2 app, though not sure that is relevant)
How do I go about post processing a FirebaseListObservable?

Comment: Until there is a release, you might want to use a specific semver rather than a range. Use `2.0.0-beta.7` not `2.0.0-beta.7-pre`. Also, check your `node_modules` directory for multiple `rxjs` modules, as you only want one. Run `npm list rxjs` to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @cartant, this probably lead me to the answer

```
 npm list rxjs =>
ionic-hello-world@ /Users/Mark/Dropbox/PP/PP
├─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.22-1
│ ├─┬ @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.15
│ │ └── rxjs@5.0.3
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.2.3
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.3
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.2.3
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/tsc-wrapped@^0.5.0
│ ├── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.25
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.1.0
```

So I did:

```
rm -Rf node_modules/ && npm install
```

and it fixed the issue.

This seems to be standard practice in the JS world, although if one has to constantly blast one's node modules, then npm doesn't seem to work that well. Bring on yarn!

Comment: I have this same issue. Anyways, I am getting this error `'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I am using windows. I assume  need to install `rm` via npm?

Comment: `rm` is just remove in unix. You'll need `rd /s /q`

Answer (score 0):

It was broken in angularfire 2.0.0-beta.7-pre. I'm using AngularFire with an Ionic 2 project.

EDIT: Issue resolved in 2.0.0-beta.8

In package.json of the main project, 
use dependency `"angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.8"`

Earlier version doesn't seem to have the map operator on FirebaseListObservable.